# Get 'Week Of' Date from Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I  have a field named 'AirDate' which is in mm/dd/yyyy format.  I'd like to create a 'WeekOf' field which uses the AirDate field to give me the WeekOf date using Tuesday as the start of the week.

AirDate = 11/11/2019, WeekOf = 11/5/2019

AirDate = 11/12/2019, WeekOf = 11/12/2019

AirDate = 11/13/2019, WeekOf = 11/12/2019
etc.

What's the proper way to write the query to return the 'WeekOf' date in this format?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ If you have any code you have tried already please add it to your post. Even if it didn't work as expected it still provides a starting point for other SO contributors to help

Answer (score 1):

`sql server` you can use `datefirst` to set `tuesday`. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
set datefirst 2
select wkTuesday = dateadd(dd, (-1)* (datepart(dw,'11/11/2019')-1), '11/11/2019')
set datefirst 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

and replace getdate() with the date that you want

```
SELECT dateadd(dd, (-1 * DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate())) + 1, getdate())
```

**EDIT**

```
declare @YourDate date = '19 NOv 2019'

declare @DayNo int

SET @DayNo = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @YourDate) < 3 THEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @YourDate) + 5 ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @YourDate) - 2 END


SELECT 'AirDate = ' + cast(@YourDate as varchar(100)) + ' , WeekOf = ' + cast( dateadd(dd, (-1 * @DayNo) + 1, @YourDate) as varchar(100))
```

Comment: That's returning the previous Sunday as the WeekOf date.  I want to use Tuesday as the start of my week, not Sunday.

Comment: @harleyberger Edited the answer